# How does askForPermission works?

Tags: actions-on-google

I want to greet the user with his name when he access my app for a second time. For this I have already implemented account linking and now I want to get his displayName and for what I have read I need to ask for his permission to access such information, so I did as it is on the following piece of code:

```
welcome(app){
    let welcomePhrase = "";

    console.log('UserId: ' + app.getUser().userId);

    if (app.isPermissionGranted()) {
        console.log('--------------- Permission granted ---------------');
        const displayName = app.getUserName().displayName;
        welcomePhrase = "Welcome back $1!".replace("$1",displayName);
    }
    else{
        console.log('--------------- Permission denied ---------------');
        this.requestPermission(app);
        welcomePhrase = "Welcome";
    }
    app.ask(welcomePhrase);
}

requestPermission (app) {
    app.askForPermission('Can I keep one information from you?', app.SupportedPermissions.NAME);
}
```

The welcome method is called from my Default welcome intent and I do can see the app asking for the permission:

[image] 
(yeah, it is in PT-BR)

What I'm not getting is what should I as a user answer, as replying "sim"(yes), "sim, você pode" (yes you can) or anything similar keeps being answered by my default fallback.

Comment: Have you seen this?
https://medium.com/google-developer-experts/handling-permissions-with-dialogflow-and-actions-on-google-b08c8f228c00

Comment: Not before seen your comment. Thanks, I was able to make it work after reading it.

Comment: I think there is way to mark the comment as answer so other people can see it as the answer.

Comment: There should be a button to upvote like the answer? I can't see anything to mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main idea is that you have to request the permission, Google asks the user for you, you received the answer back by catching the event coming back to Dialogflow.

Wassim Chegham wrote a good article: https://medium.com/google-developer-experts/handling-permissions-with-dialogflow-and-actions-on-google-b08c8f228c00

More documentation here:
https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/helpers